# Parsing a XML atribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have been trying to parse an XML response from a web service. This is an example of what it is returning.

```
    var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><campaign guid='799223B1-24A7-4F01-8DAE-632E6F68F845'><LeaderBoard><Target Rank='1' TotalScore='138000' FirstName='Shane' LastName='Foster' TargetCompanyName='[Acme]' DisplayName=''>Hello World</Target></LeaderBoard></campaign>",
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc),
        $title = $xml.find("Target");

        alert($title.text());
```

This works, but I want to get the values of the attributes. I try adding:

```
        $title = $xml.find("Target").attr("TotalScore");
```

but I get nothing back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an element's value instead of the attribute's value which is already added to the var when you do .attr();

Try this:

```
<script>
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><campaign guid='799223B1-24A7-4F01-8DAE-632E6F68F845'><LeaderBoard><Target Rank='1' TotalScore='138000' FirstName='Shane' LastName='Foster' TargetCompanyName='[Acme]' DisplayName=''>Hello World</Target></LeaderBoard></campaign>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("Target").attr("TotalScore");
    alert($title);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach pal first is that you need to throw the path of xml file using ajax to webservice then let webservice get your data at the backend side

```
     /// convert xml data to datatable
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     /// your xml file path
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLData\\here.xml");

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];


    /// new datatable to store value of xml datas
    DataTable newDt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    newDt.Columns.Add("Title");
    newDt.Columns.Add("Author");


    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string Title = "";
            string author = "";

            if (row["Title"] != null && row["Title"].ToString() != "")
            {
                Title = row["Title"].ToString();

            }
            if (row["Author"] != null && row["Author"].ToString() != "")
            {
                author = row["Author"].ToString();
            }

            newDt.Rows.Add(Title, author);

        }



    }
```